# gulp watch doesn't watch

Tags: javascript, node.js, task, gulp

Following is my gulpfile.js. There are a couple of more tasks in it and all are working fine - but the last task, `watch` doesn't.

I've tried every possible combination of paths and files and what so ever, but still I don't have luck. I've read many answers on this here, but couldn't solve my problem. I tried to run gulp.watch with and without requiring gulp-watch, tried several different approaches on how to set up the task and so on and so on...

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var babelify = require('babelify');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var watch = require('gulp-watch');

gulp.task('application', function() {
    return browserify('./public/resources/jsx/application.js')
        .transform(babelify, { stage: 0 })
        .bundle()
        .on('error', function(e){
            console.log(e.message);

            this.emit('end');
        })
        .pipe(source('appBundle.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/resources/jsx'));
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('./public/resources/jsx/project/*.js',['application'])
});
```

Can someone suggest a solution?

EDIT:

Here's the console output:

```
michael@michael-desktop:/opt/PhpstormProjects/app_april_2015$ gulp watch
[23:05:03] Using gulpfile /opt/PhpstormProjects/app_april_2015/gulpfile.js
[23:05:03] Starting 'watch'...
[23:05:03] Finished 'watch' after 13 ms
```

Comment: What are you doing? What isn't working?

Comment: After starting the task it runs once, finishes without error but never gets triggered again. No matter what I do with the file. @JMM

Comment: "Starting the task" means `gulp watch`? "the file" means `application.js`?

Comment: "Starting the task" shall mean starting gulp watch

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should `return` watch:

```
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    return gulp.watch('./public/resources/jsx/project/*.js',['application'])
});
```

`watch` is an `async` method, so the only way Gulp can know that something is happening is if you return a `promise`, which watch does.

**Edit**

As @JMM stated, `watch` doesn't return a Promise. It returns an [EventEmitter](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_class_events_eventemitter).

Comment: @andrerpena returing a promise from a task is only one of several ways of indicating when it's complete. And `gulp.watch()` is documented as returning an EventEmitter.

Comment: @JMM. Thanks, I fixed that. Michael, you are welcome.

Comment: @andrerpena So this begs the question: if `gulp.watch()` returns an EventEmitter, and the OP's console output shows the `watch` task completing -- how does your answer, returning `gulp.watch()`, have this effect?