# gulp.watch - To return or not return

Tags: gulp

The official documentation for `gulpjs/gulp` has a sample `gulpfile.js` which provides a `watch` task that has no `return` statement:

`gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch(paths.scripts, ['scripts']);
    gulp.watch(paths.images, ['images']);
});`

That approach fits my needs, because I want to watch over multiple sets of files with different tasks associated to each of them.

But I've found in the community a few bold statements saying that `gulp.watch` should be returned, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29929941/5572030), that proposes the following code:

`gulp.task('watch', function() {
    return gulp.watch('./public/resources/jsx/project/*.js',['application'])
});`

I understand that tasks should return, so that other tasks using them as part of their workflow are able to act accordingly to their async nature, but for the special case of a `watch` task, which is always the last in a list of tasks, there might make sense not to return it, making it possible to have multiple watches.

Does that make sense? Can I safely omit the return from my `watch` task in order to be able to have multiple instances of `gulp.watch` in it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I prefer all task have return statement. Otherwise you can read a false "Finished watch".
When task are complex, it is not possible create a single watch for a several pattern of files. In this cases, my solution is based on to create a supergroup task called "watch" that depends on single watches with its return statements.

```
gulp.task("watch", [
    "watch-css",
    "watch-js",
    "watch-inject-html"
]);

gulp.task("watch-css", function() {
  return gulp.watch(sources.css, ["css"]);
});

gulp.task("watch-js", function() {
  return gulp.watch(sources.js, ["js"]);
});

gulp.task("watch-inject-html", function() {
  return gulp.watch(sources.inject, ["inject-html"]);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For gulp4 you can do this:

```js
gulp.task('watch:images', gulp.parallel(
    function () { return gulp.watch(SRC_DIR+'/*', gulp.task('images:copy')); },
    function () { return gulp.watch(SRC_DIR+'/svg/**/*', gulp.task('images:svg')); },
    function () { return gulp.watch(SRC_DIR+'/backgrounds/**/*', gulp.task('images:backgrounds')); },
    function () { return gulp.watch(SRC_DIR+'/heads/**/*', gulp.task('images:heads')); }
));
```

However the anonymous functions inside `gulp.parallel` will report as `<anonymous>` in gulp output.

You can give the functions names and they will show up in gulp output instead of anonymous.

```
gulp.task('watch:images', gulp.parallel(
    function foobar1 () { return gulp.watch(SRC_DIR+'/*', gulp.task('images:copy')); },
    function foobar2 () { return gulp.watch(SRC_DIR+'/svg/**/*', gulp.task('images:svg')); },
    function foobar3 () { return gulp.watch(SRC_DIR+'/backgrounds/**/*', gulp.task('images:backgrounds')); },
    function foobar4 () { return gulp.watch(SRC_DIR+'/heads/**/*', gulp.task('images:heads')); }
));
```

However it seems that `return gulp.watch(/* ... */)` is not ideal.  When watching if you hit CTRL-C you get a nice big error about those watch tasks not completing.

It seems like if you have a stream you are supposed to return the stream.

e.g. `return gulp.src(...).pipe()`

...but if you are doing something async or don't have a stream you should be calling the callback instead of returning something.

Would be happy to be pointed to the relevant docs for this (return vs callback) as I didn't see a clear explanation in the gulp docs I read.  I tried going all callback (no returning streams) and ran into other issues...but possibly they were caused by something else.

Dealing with multiple watches in a single task the following way doesn't report `<anonymous>` and also doesn't complain when you CTRL-C while watching.  My understanding is that since the watch tasks are open-ended we just inform gulp that as far as gulp cares when it comes to making sure stuff runs in a specific order, these are started and gulp can move on.

```
gulp.task('watch:images', function (done) {
    gulp.watch(SRC_DIR+'/*', gulp.task('images:copy'));
    gulp.watch(SRC_DIR+'/svg/**/*', gulp.task('images:svg'));
    gulp.watch(SRC_DIR+'/backgrounds/**/*', gulp.task('images:backgrounds'));
    gulp.watch(SRC_DIR+'/heads/**/*', gulp.task('images:heads'));
    return done();
});
```

Comment: It is just "done();"  not "return done();"  See https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/getting-started/async-completion#using-an-error-first-callback.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can omit return for watch task. I also don't support structures that has multiple watches. More over you are only going to use watch task on development environment, so go ahead and ignore return for watch task.

Comment: Why do you say you don't like tasks that have multiple watches?

Comment: Hmm.. I am trying to picture a scenario where I need to start two or more watch yet both can be done in one. Can you provide me a real life example Also since two watches running, both async; won't the log generated be harder to read at times?

Comment: My scenario is watching simultaneously for changes in structure (html), style (css) and behavior (js) in front-end web development. About the async stdout log, that might not be an issue, since what would trigger any of the watch events would be known by the developer (for example, saving changes to a Sass file).

Comment: OK. But you can create a single watch to look for changes in any of those files. Isn't creating individual watches for html, css & js not only inferior but you gotta start each of them from CLI. Please refer to the `watch` task written on the official npm gulp page [LINK](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp). One watch task listening to changes with no returns.

Comment: There's a misunderstanding here. I've seen the example from the official docs, it is even copied in my question. And I don't mean to have multiple tasks, each of them with one watch. I mean to have a single task, with multiple watches inside it and no return, exactly as in the mentioned example in the docs. The whole question is regarding the lack of a `return` statement for that case, because I've read in lots of places people stating that tasks must return. So we are both preferring the same approach (the one from the official docs), but my question is if it is fine not having it to return.