# Error while "gulp watch"

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-watch

Please, could anyone help me with Grunt error?

gulpfile.js: http://pastebin.com/c2Ux9pxc

package.json: http://pastebin.com/UFkWqWVY

output: http://pastebin.com/s1c3HEnC

I added "return" to gulp (as it written [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29929606/gulp-watch-doesnt-watch)) so that it became

```
32 return gulp.watch('./sass/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
55 return gulp.watch('src/jade/*.jade', ['jade']);
```

but the result is still the same.

Comment: Do you use gulp or grant? These are two different systems?

Comment: can you add your gulpfile ? You just added the output log from gulp.

Comment: Oops.. I'm sorry, it's a mistake. I use "gulp".
Also I added gulpfile.
But now there is a previous error, which I have about a day ago:
    gulp: command not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your error, it seems that the port you’re trying to use is below 1024. Those ports require root access to be bound. Use a higher one.